# Hi I want to make an Start Stop button in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Hi i wanted to make an clickbot for cookieclicker in python3. It works but i want to make an stop button function .

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time 
chromedriver_path = "My Chromedriver path ;)"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

time.sleep(5)
cookie = driver.find_element_by_id("bigCookie")
time.sleep(5)

while True:

    cookie.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the loop and add a condition to stop the click action, or, you can try to implement a Listener to stop the script when you press on a specific key.